# Urdu fonts issue in Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: fonts

I have installed Lubuntu 18.04 on my Compaq 6910p, I customized Firefox fonts and LightDM gtk as well. The issue is whenever I copy MS fonts (calibri times new roman and some other) to fonts directory the fonts selected in Firefox and LightDM automatically selects that fonts. Could you guys please help me?

Comment: Which Urdu font are you using?

Comment: In firefox Nafees pakistani naksh and in LightDM ubuntu medium.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will notice a difference if you install the `fonts-nafees` package from the Ubuntu archive and switch to an Urdu locale. `fonts-nafees` includes the Nafees Nastaleeq font.